# Using the quote characters in a Symfony2 Regex validator

Tags: regex, symfony, quote

Here my problem:

```
@Assert\Regex(
*     pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\"]*$/",
*     groups={"creation", "creation_logged"}
* )
```

I'm using the regex validator of Symfony 2, I want to allow the quote characters in my regex, but unfortunately the pattern close at this quote, I have a beautiful error. I tried to add an antislash before it, but it doesn't work too !

I'm not the only guy to have this problem: http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2/browse_thread/thread/d0ade380e4f5a64e but no answer too :s

Is there a way to add the quote characters in the pattern ?

Comment: it's just a thought, don't know if it works. have you tried double quote ("")?

Comment: I'm curious: What is a beautiful error and can I have one too?

Comment: @Tim, because there is a sympathetic ghost xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the character code instead:

```
* @Assert\Regex(
*     pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\x22]*$/",
*     groups={"creation", "creation_logged"}
* )
```